# Running PHPUnit in Laravel's Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, vagrant, homestead

I'm using Homestead to serve my Laravel application. I'm trying to run PHPUnit. According to the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/testing#introduction):

> An example test file is provided in the app/tests directory. After
>   installing a new Laravel application, simply run `phpunit` on the
>   command line to run your tests.

Well, when I'm "simply running" `phpunit` in my project root (inside the Homestead environment) I get this:

**The program 'phpunit' is currently not installed.**

Do I need to install PHPUnit separately then? The documentation does not mention it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can install it globally on the system using.

```
composer global require phpunit/phpunit
```

However, if you need different versions for different projects this can cause issues.

The alternative option is to use the version installed as part of your dependencies by referencing the path to your `vendor` directory.

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

You could even add an alias to your aliases file in your `~/Homestead` directory. That way you're always using the phpunit version that is installed with your project dependencies.

```
alias phpunit=./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

You'll need to restart the homestead box to make use of the alias.

Comment: For me this installed phpunit v5.1 which is not compatible with Laravel at the moment. Use `composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.4.*"` to specify the version.

Comment: Homestead now sets up this alias automatically.

Answer (score 8):

You can install it globally with:

```
$ composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.4.*"
# then use
$ phpunit
```

or you can use it with your local composer:

```
$ composer require "phpunit/phpunit=4.4.*"
# then
$ vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: The second approach didn't work for me; phpunit says `You need to set up the project dependencies using the following commands: ...`. The global install works, though.

Comment: If anyone needs to support a specific version of PHP with PHPUnit, checkout the supported versions page: https://phpunit.de/supported-versions.html

Answer (score 3):

Since it's a package required for development, Laravel provide PHPunit(require-dev section in composer), you should find it in vendor's folder :

```
$ your_app/vendor/bin/
```

You can run the command from the root of your app folder by typing :

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I hope it will help !